# I am getting error with python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code for 4 properties to scrape data but I'm only getting data from just first field "title" and the other 3 fields return empty results. could anyone please guide me how can I fix this issue. thanks!
 here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import pandas as pd
import csv

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') # 1. html , 2. parser
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):

    try:
        title = soup.find('span',class_="text-info h4",id=False).find('strong').text
    except:
        title = 'empty'  
    print(title)
    try:
        add = soup.find('div',class_="col-xs-12 col-sm-4",id=False).find('strong')
    except:
        add = 'empty add'  
    print(add)  
    try:
        phone = soup.find('div',class_="col-xs-12 col-sm-4",id=False).text
    except:
        phone = 'empty phone'  
    print(phone)


def main():
    url = "https://www.dobsearch.com/people-finder/view.php?searchnum=287404084791&sessid=vusqgp50pm8r38lfe13la8ta1l"
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: can you declare which parts of website you are trying to work on?

Comment: I need just main title (name of person Age(64)), mainn address and main phone no. all these information are on the top of each records. other records and phone no I don't need I need just main info that is on the top row of each listing. thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the second one you are giving a class that has occurred before the one that you want so you need to change the class or go through multiple findings. and this happened for the third one too. this kinds of classes (col-xs-12) are some bootstrap classes and they are common classes to use so in general they are not good attempts to be used in finding (or you should make more complicated finds). and as I can see this site doesn't have much unique classes so I think you should use multiple find methods to get what you want. and another thing that I can say is to not use try...except unless you know what you are getting from that part.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but bro which method shoud ld I use to scrape data?